Connecting to Google Analytics 4 with C# .NET Core desktop app - use database field contents instead of .json file
I have a C# / .NET Core desktop app that connects fine to Google Analytics 4 using the Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta package. I have a .json file that Google created so I can access Google Analytics and I use it in my code as below.
string credentialsJsonPath = projectRootPath + "filename.json";
       
BetaAnalyticsDataClient client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClientBuilder
    {
        CredentialsPath = credentialsJsonPath,
    }.Build();

I have stored the content of the filename.json file as a base 64 encoded database column in a table in SQL Server that my app is connected to and the database column is defined as shown here:
FileBytes (varbinary(max), not null)

How do I replace the CredentialsPath = credentialsJsonPath line above to read the contents of my database column, rather having to open a physical .json file like I am doing now?
Cheers
John
